# Wrong comparator show in Hybris Backoffice for enum field

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, advanced-search, backoffice

I've got a peculiar problem in Hybris Backoffice.  When I search for Promotion Rules (Marketing->Promotion Rules), one of the available fields is `Type`. Yet, when I try to use that field, the comparator in the advanced search widget is incorrect.  The type of `status` field is `HybrisEnumValue`. However the comparator only contains three options: `In`, `Is Empty` and `Is not empty`:

[image]

As an example, Order Status is also a field with type `HybrisEnumValue`, however in the advanced search it does show correct comparator options:

[image]

Obviously, this `In` operator causes problems down the line when searching. How can get it to display the correct comparator values, that is, `Equals` instead of `In`?

**EDIT:** As evident from the answer by @geffchang I didn't make it clear that I can only select a single value:

[image]

Further, when Hybris translates the query into SQL, it ends up with a wrong WHERE clause: `WHERE item_t0.p_status  IN ?` - instead of `in` it should have `=`

Answer (score 0):

What issues are you seeing?

Personally, I think this is fine. `In` lets you select multiple values in `OR` fashion. So, Status in (`Published`, `Unpublished`) gives you both published and unpublished rules. If you want `Published` only, that's also fine.

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't allow selecting multiple values.  I can only select one value from the dropdown.  Further, this causes a SQL exception because it's using incorrect syntax.  It translates the selection into this where clause `WHERE item_t0.p_status  IN ?` - instead of `in` it should have `=`.

Comment: @AleksG I updateed my answer with a screenshot. That's what it should look like.

Comment: That's not what it looks like - I updated my question with the extra screenshot. What version of Hybris are you using?

Comment: @AleksG Just compared our screenshots, and they do look different. I'm using 1905.13. Yours might be a bug, or not properly set-up.

Comment: I'm on 1905, but I think it's an older version of 1905.  Upgrading to a newer version may be an issue, as I have multi-million dollar live sites running on the installation, so any version upgrade is very risky and takes potentially months to test

Comment: I'll see if I can force it to you a different editor

Comment: which mysql version are you running? which mysql connector? because seems like it is an issue translating the sql clause

Answer (score 0):

this is due to OOTB functionality , because of which "Equals" operator is replaced by "IN" operator , you can add above bean in your backoffice-spring.xml and issue will be fixed -:
[bean_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmCYY.png)